# How do I do these VOR time and distance calculations?

Tags: navigation, vor

I'm trying to figure out the calculation to these questions:

> A pilot tracking a VOR turns 90 degrees from current heading. The
>   pilot notes that it takes 3.0 minutes for the plane to intercept the
>   radial 5 degrees from where it previously was. What is the time to
>   VOR?

And:

> Using the previous question, what is the aircraft speed if the
>   distance to travel is 100 miles?

I used the formulas my professor gave me and the numbers are coming out unrealistic to me. Could someone walk me through how to get the correct answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the formula you are looking for:
(You can use this formula to answer your first question. I'm not entirely clear on what the second question means.)
[image]

Here is a nice discussion of the time/distance check from the Flight Learnings website: [time/distance to station](http://www.flightlearnings.com/2012/08/09/time-and-distance-check-from-a-station/)

Comment: Thank you! I was thinking that the result was seconds to station not minutes because you had to convert minuses between bearing to seconds!